# How to slice numpy array across multiple dimensions by passing a list?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

Lets say we have a numpy array `A` with shape `(m_1,m_2,...,m_n)` where `n` can be variable. Given a list of  `n` integers `[i_1,...,i_n]` I want to slice `A` as follows: `A[i_1][i_2]...[i_n]`

What is the  easiest way to do this?

Comment: Use a tuple, not a list

Comment: @hpaulj thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see comment of hpaulj: Use a tuple, not a list

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).